# Where can I find new Cocoa Touch Framework project in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, frameworks, project

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5823-how-to-create-a-cocoapod-in-swift) to learn to make a cocoapod. Unfortunately the tutorial instructs to create a "Cocoa Touch Framework" when that no longer exists in current XCode.

What's the current equivalent, that I can use for the purposes of this tutorial / to make a cocoapod?

Answer (score 2):

The answer isn't too complicated: it's the "Framework" option. [image]

A **Static Library** is pure object code (a.k.a. compiled code), and it cannot contain images, storyboards, etc. Pure object code also means you can't read the code files which makes it pretty much un-debuggable.

A **Metal Library** lets you develop using the [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) library, basically for 3D graphics and GPU stuff.

**Framework** is a cocoapod framework. Tried and tested and loved by all Apple Developers.